# Email Takeover Scam?

Tags: email, account-security, spam, scam

I've been receiving a lot of email lately intended for "Daniel L...", a person with the same last name and same first initial as me. It appears this person has requested information from dozens of colleges, car rentals, business opportunities, etc; and had all the information sent to my email address. I have a short, basic email address so this has happened before but not nearly to this extent. In previous cases, it was nothing malicious; most likely the person either entered the wrong email address in a form, or perhaps didn't actually didn't want to provide their own actual email in that scenario for whatever reason.

In these recent cases with "Daniel" however, I am perplexed what the explanation could be. Clearly he couldn't have mistakenly entered my email while legitimately requesting information from so many colleges and other places. Again, to reiterate, it appears "Daniel" has entered my email in many, **probably 50-100 different websites requesting information**. He would not have actually received any of that requested information.

**Is this behavior consistent with any well-know scams related to trying to takeover a particular email account, especially a highly desirable (aka "og" address)?** Perhaps he is playing a long con, and thinks he is building a case to show he is the rightful owner of the email address?

For example, maybe he intends to go to the email domain owner and say something like, "look I know this email address has received these exact hundred emails over the past year, this proves it should be turned over to me"??? It seems very flimsy, but I just wanted to make sure this isn't some scam I am not aware of.

Comment: I get dozens of emails destined for other people around the world every week. In some cases, they are small business owners who are using my email by mistake with business partners and vendors. I've been dealing with some of them for *years*. Without details and more information, we can only guess about what is actually going on in your case. But it is perfectly reasonable that they keep entering their email wrong.

Comment: We are not a scam site. So this isn't about security. 
And you are speculating that this is some kind of a "con". There's no way to take over an account by getting 3rd parties to email it ... We get at least one question almost exactly like this every month. So, no, this was not "quickly closed". This is off-topic, and without specific technical details around malicious behaviour, we can only guess what the intent is,

Comment: And by the way, I know of someone who signs up to websites for information and uses my email address. It's not a scam, the person is real and our names are similar. I can't imagine what's going through their head.

Comment: *"He would not have actually received any of that requested information."* and *"look I know this email address has received these exact hundred emails over the past year"* - these two statements look mutually exclusive to me.